# How to set a %?RESOURCES key during development?

Tags: module, raku

In a module I'm developing, there will be a file `config` provided in the `resources` directory, and so it can be accessed as `%?RESOURCES<config>` within the code I am developing.

Whilst writing and testing the code, I need to set %?RESOURCES. How can this be done?

At the start of the module, in the development stage, I have `use lib 'lib'`.

I haven't zef-installed the Module yet, so `%?RESOURCES` is Nil.

The META6.json file contains `"resources": [ "config" ]` .

Comment: `%?RESOURCES` works perfectly fine for not-yet-installed modules. You just want to access `%?RESOURCES` outside the scope of a module (i.e. a bin script or test file, neither of which have access to `%?RESOURCES`), but to do that you need to provide your own interface similarly to https://github.com/Raku/roast/blob/057ba3538457457bc25163d63715e70450243115/packages/CurrentDistributionOne/lib/CurrentDistributionOne.pm6#L5

Comment: @ugexe I looked at link, but how to get a value into `%?RESOURCES` ? Could you provide some more boiler plate example?

Comment: Did you add the resources info to the META6.json?

Comment: edited to show config is in resources, as per documentation.

Comment: Are you running using the command line option `-Ilib`?  When I used to develop using `use lib 'lib'` in code, I couldn't access `%?RESOURCES`, but `-Ilib` allowed it.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, I don't think it's possible to *set* any variable with the twigil `?`. Unlike those with the `*` twigil, they're not dynamic variables, but simply a reflection of some core data structure.
In the case of [`%?RESOURCES`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#%?RESOURCES), the documentation says:

> The %?RESOURCES variable is not implemented as a plain Hash, but as an instance of the Distribution::Resources type, so do not expect to see all available resource files in a distribution by printing or by using other ways to inspect its value. Instead, use the API described above to access particular files

As you see in the documentation for [`Distribution::Resource`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Distribution::Resource), which *cough* could be improved by *a lot*, there's no interface for even setting the values.

If what you're looking for is to *install* a resource during runtime, it's probably not advisable to do so. But TIMTOWDI, and the previous class might give you some hints on how to do it.